# How to Get the data from the Object class in flutter

Tags: flutter, class, dart, object, member

How to get data from Object class of its members.

```
final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;
```

The args returns the Object class. How can I access it members without defining the class.

Previously I access it like this.

```
final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as NameArgument;
```

an then use it like

```
args.name
```

Answer (score 0):

I access it by defining it as dynamic and then access through `[]`.

Like

```
final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as dynamic;
  print("This is the Args of the Data ${args['message']}");
```

Comment: why to use dynamic when you can typecast?

Comment: @JiteshMohite Can you give an example of it. So, that I understand.